# Eliminar caracteres de una cadena

Tags: sql

Tengo una base en Access, con al rededor de 1000 registros,la cual convierto a un archivo SQL. 
Las imágenes son guardadas en Hexadecimal de la siguiente manera.

```
0x6C7400006C340000FFD8FFE000104A46494600010100000100010000FFDB00430006040506050406060506070706080A100A0A09090A140E0F0C1017141818171416161A1D251F1A1B231C1616202C20232627292A29191F2D302D28.......
```

La situación es que necesito quitar los primero caracteres antes del FFD8 pero respetando el 0x.

¿Alguna idea para leer cada registro y eliminar esos caracteres?

Gracias.

Comment: y como estas haciendo la conversion? lo que pedis se soluciona con un substr en casi todos los lenguajes

Answer (score 0):

Intenta de esta manera:

```
declare @texto varchar(5000) = '0x6C7400006C340000FFD8FFE000104A46494600010100000100010000FFDB00430006040506050406060506070706080A100A0A09090A140E0F0C1017141818171416161A1D251F1A1B231C1616202C20232627292A29191F2D302D28.......'

select ('0x' + substring(@texto, CHARINDEX('FFD8', @texto, 1), len(@texto))) resultado
```

Comment: esto le saca el 0x

Comment: Si, puedes adaptarlo a lo que necesitas

Comment: @JoséAlfredoPoot si le ayudas a adaptarlo para que sea de mayor utilidad ?